# Overlay SharedElement with enter Activity element

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have two activities:

- MainActivity: sharedElement
- DeatilActivity: sharedElement, bottomLayout

I'm trying to make a transition between the activities and overlap the sharedElement with the bottomLayout. The bottomLayout has a Slide transition as well.

This is the transition file:

```
<transitionSet 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:transitionOrdering="together">
<fade>
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
    </targets>
</fade>
<slide android:slideEdge="bottom">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@id/layout_bottom" />
    </targets>
</slide>
```

The effect that I got till now is this:

[image]

I know I can do that if I make the animation manually when the transition is finished but I want to do it in the same time.

I've google it but I haven't found anything about that, I tried setting elevation to bottomLayout but didn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this??

Thanks in advance!!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The question is a long time ago. I face the same problem in my transition and I found way to work around it. Just in case other people would face the same problem, Here is my solution.

By default, share element views are drawn on top of entire view hierarchy in window ViewOverlay. If you'd like to disable it, add following attribute in your AppTheme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
</style>
```